How to test Quarkus scheduler job
I have this method, in the following class. This is java quarkus application
and this method is simply removing data.
@ApplicationScoped
public class DeprecatedDataRemovalBean {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DeprecatedDataRemovalBean.class);

    @Inject
    JobService jobService;

    //at 3 o'clock in the morning
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 3 * * ?", timeZone = "Europe/Berlin")
    void removeDeprecatedData(ScheduledExecution execution) {
        LOG.info("Starting the data removal at " + execution.getScheduledFireTime());
        try {
            jobService.removeDataIfReadCountIsMoreThanOne();
            LOG.info("Data removal process completed successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("An error occurred during the data removal process: ", e);
        }
    }
}

It's quarkus scheduler. Now I want to write a test which would set time at 3 and make sure job is run at 3. How can this be achieved?
I've tried some tests, but they didn't work. Any idea, please?
cron is scheduled to run everyday at 3.

I would not test this particular code. I recommend testing jobService.removeDataIfReadCountIsmoreThanOne() instead.

jobService.removeDataIfReadCountIsmoreThanOne() I have tested it with integration tests

Inject your jobServixe as a Spy, then verify that jobServixe has been called.
